# Excel Chart Moves Slightly Despite Setting Location

Tags: vba, excel, gantt-chart

I have created a Gantt chart that sits directly next to the row the data is pulled from so everything is in one neat line. There are several months of data, so I have created two buttons (Next Page/Previous Page) that add/subtract 30 from the minimum and maximum values of the x-axis. Because everything is lined up Gantt-table-style, I have been trying to reset the chart's location to it's original one. Unfortunately, the chart still moves creating a small gap between the chart and my data. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

None of my charts corners lay on the corner of a cell, plus some columns may be re sized later on.

```
Private Sub NEXT_PG_Click()
    Dim chart_height As Single, chart_length As Single, chart_top As Single, chart_left As Single

    'Saving original position to save later
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2")
       chart_height = .Height
       chart_width = .Width
       chart_top = .Top
       chart_left = .Left
    End With

    'Displaying next 30 days of data
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart.Axes(xlValue)
        .MinimumScale = .MinimumScale + 30
        .MaximumScale = .MaximumScale + 30
    End With

    'Trying to set original location and size
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2")
        .Height = chart_height
        .Width = chart_width
        .Left = chart_left
        .Top = chart_top
    End With    
End Sub
```

[Added images](https://github.com/AKhillerParty/Gantt_Chart/issues/1)

**Update**: As a temporary fix, I have tried to set the location of the plot area to a specific location, but this makes it worse. Please see the change to the attempted with statement below:

```
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart.PlotArea
    .Height = Range("A8:A30").Height
    .Width = Range("J6:U6").Width
    .Top = Range("J8").Top
    .Left = Range("J8").Left
End With
```

Comment: Are we missing more of your code?  I don't understand why you are touching the location.  If you change one property at a time (instead of all 4), does it only move for specific ones?  If so, does the movement depend on the absolute value of the property?  It might be the case that Excel stores the position with more precision than it can actually render at and does an effective rounding when you send the value back in.  Does it happen if you run the code several times?  Or just the first time?

Comment: Hi Byron, thank you for your response. When I step through my last ' with  ' statement, the graph does not move during any of the assignments even though I see the variables are assigned. What is odd is the graph will move each time I click the next page button, but by the fifth time, it will end up back where is started.

Comment: I am adding [a link to a few images](https://github.com/AKhillerParty/Gantt_Chart/issues/1) that might make it clearer. In the image, I used the previous button, but this uses the same code. I should also note that my graph has a secondary axis to create the current date line.

Comment: Sometimes the `Zoom in` / `Zoom out` feature does not work properly. Try `100%` as see if it helps

Comment: This worked....hahaha. Thank you please post as an answer.